# CSS var : attributes refer to the same variable but measure different

Tags: css, css-variables, css-calc

```
<html>
<body>
<div></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

```
:root { 
    --scrollbar-width: calc(100vw - 100%);
}

body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5CAq.jpg);  
  width: var(--scrollbar-width);
  height: var(--scrollbar-width);
}
```

The width and height of the div element refer to the same CSS custom variable(--scrollbar-width) but its width and height measure different in the browser. Why is that??

Comment: because the percentage will not resolve the same way .. the calculation is not done inside the variable but inside the property

Comment: @TemaniAfif My doubt is solved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the first comment. The calculation arn't done inside of the definition but inside of the property.

This results in the following:

`height: var(--scrollbar-width);` is equal to `height: calc(100vw - 100%);` where `100%` is calculated relative to the height of the element. While `width: var(--scrollbar-width);` or `width: calc(100vw - 100%);` would result in a calculation where 100% is relative to the elements width.

That's the reason why even tho you are referencing the same custom property the results for *width* and *height* are different.

Comment: My doubt is solved. Thank you very much.